# Как связать значения из CSV-файлов с выборкой из базы данных?

Tags: birt

Я пытаюсь построить отчёт c помощью BIRT. Определяю несколько источников данных - два CSV-файла и база данных MySQL. Запрос, получающий данные из базы данных, выглядит следующим образом:

```
SELECT applicationType, STATUS, COUNT(*) 
FROM cards
GROUP BY applicationType, STATUS;
```

Далее я создала таблицу, которая имеет три столбца, соответствующие этим значениям из выборки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я хочу вместо `applicationType` и `status` выводить значения из CSV-файлов. 1-ый файл, *apptype.csv*, имеет следующую структуру:

```
applicationType,apptypedescr
1,"Приложение общего типа"
2,"Приложение типа 1"
...
```

и второй файл, *statuscards.csv*, имеет структуру:

```
status,statuscards
1,"Заблокирована"
2,"В эксплуатации"
...
```

И вместо

```
Тип приложения | Статус карты | Количество
---------------|--------------|------------
1              | 2            | 55
```

я хочу выводить

```
Тип приложения         | Статус карты   | Количество
-----------------------|----------------|------------
Приложение общего типа | В эксплуатации | 55
```

И я создала связку для выборки из MySQL и первого файла как `New Joint Data Set`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако как изменить таблицу теперь, я не знаю. Насколько я понимаю,
 `[applicationType]` в первом столбце нужно заменить на `[apptypedescr]`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

однако это поле в таблицу не перетаскивается, есть возможность добавить его на отчёт только вне таблицы. Как связать эти значения из CSV-файлов с данными из выборки из базы данных в таблице?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось это сделать, установив новый набор данных для таблицы в *Properties -> Binding -> DataSet*. После этого отчет был построен правильно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]